# How can i combine the index pages of multiple CRUD?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, crud

I'm trying to combine the index pages of my CRUDs into one as a main home page, this is what I tried however it comes up with an underfined method each error, any ideas? Also not sure how to get the redirects to go to it after creating and deletion.

```
<h1>Weather forecasts</h1>

<%= link_to 'Search by City', new_cityweather_path(@cityweathers) %>
<%= link_to 'Search by Postcode', new_postcodeweather_path(@postcodeweathers) %>
<h1>Listing Postcodeweathers</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Postcode</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @postcodeweathers.each do |postcodeweather| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= postcodeweather.postcode %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', postcodeweather %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_postcodeweather_path(postcodeweather) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', postcodeweather, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h1>Listing Cityweathers</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @cityweathers.each do |cityweather| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= cityweather.city %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', cityweather %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cityweather_path(cityweather) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', cityweather, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please tell us what you mean with `it doesn't work`, I think most probably it's an issue with the controller. Are you sure that you are correctly loading the data into the controller's instance variables?

Comment: It comes up with an undefined method each error

Comment: You're not initializing those variables (`@cityweathers`, etc.) in the controller (home_controller or whatsitcalled)

Answer (score 1):

You can define separate controller which can be said as main controller as like:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @postcodeweathers = PostCodeWeather.all
    @cityweathers = CityWeather.all
  end
end
```

Then, the template `views/main/index.html.erb` can use [partial](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) as:

```
<h1>Weather forecasts</h1>

<%= link_to 'Search by City', new_cityweather_path(@cityweathers) %>
<%= link_to 'Search by Postcode', new_postcodeweather_path(@postcodeweathers) %>

<%= render 'post_code_weathers/index' %>

<%= render 'city_weathers/index' %>
```

Then, the partial `views/post_code_weathers/_index.html.erb` will be as:

```
<h1>Listing Postcodeweathers</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Postcode</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @postcodeweathers.each do |postcodeweather| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= postcodeweather.postcode %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', postcodeweather %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_postcodeweather_path(postcodeweather) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', postcodeweather, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And, the another partial `views/city_weathers/_index.html.erb` go like this:

```
<h1>Listing Cityweathers</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @cityweathers.each do |cityweather| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= cityweather.city %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', cityweather %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cityweather_path(cityweather) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', cityweather, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, your create and delete action on the postcodeweathers controller can be:

```
class PostCodeWeatherController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # create code goes here
    redirect_to main_index_path
  end

  def delete
    # delete code goes here
    redirect_to main_index_path
  end
end
```

Same type of actions in cityweathers controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the additional variable inside the index method of the corresponding controller?

(NOTE: this will combine both objects into the index page of PostCodeWeather)

```
class PostCodeWeathersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @postcodeweathers = PostCodeWeather.all
    @cityweathers = CityWeather.all
  end

end
```

This will allow you to access both sets of records in your index view.

As far as redirecting to the index page after creation and deletion, you should be able to add this inside the desired methods in the controller.

```
def create
  @cityweather = CityWeather.new(params[:city_weather])
  if @cityweather.save
    redirect_to action: "index"
  end
end
```